# Search for largest word match in a vocabulary from a given string

Tags: regex, string, python-3.x, list

I have a string `the big cat in the zoo`, and my vocabulary has `["in the zoo", "the zoo"]`
i cant do a  direct search , have to search the combinations:
   1) zoo
   2) the zoo
   3) in the zoo
and return only `"in the zoo"`, that is the biggest matching string
how to do this reverse search  and match in python

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Why not also search for `in the`?  This type of longest substring problem sounds like it might need a dynamic programming solution.  I don't think that the regex part is really involved here.

Comment: i need the last word to be there, that is all combination of zoo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could try something along the lines of this -

```
str1 = "the big cat in the zoo"

vocabulary = ["in the zoo", "the zoo"]

str1 = str1.split()

for first, last in itertools.combinations(range(len(str1)), 2):
    new_str = ' '.join(str1[first:last+1])
    print (new_str)
```

This gives you the output,

```
the big
the big cat
the big cat in
the big cat in the
the big cat in the zoo
big cat
big cat in
big cat in the
big cat in the zoo
cat in
cat in the
cat in the zoo
in the
in the zoo
the zoo
```

Edit it however you want to change it to use it for your problem's conditions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort your list items by descending length.
2. Loop throug your list items with `if (mystring.Contains(vocabularyItem)) ...`